# Force newline, but collapse vertical space

Tags: spacing, graphics

I'm trying to create a block of [subfigures](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats) with no space between them,

[image: result]

The above is the desired result, but the way I did it feels hacky.

I used a [newline forcer followed by negative vertical space](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/breaking.htm)

```
\\[-28pt]
```

Is there a better way to do this? (collapse the vertical space that appears by default between lines 123 and 456 in the figure?)

Source:

```
\begin{centering}
\begin{figure}
\begin{centering}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
    \caption{1}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1.png}
    \label{fig1}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
    \caption{2}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2.png}
    \label{fig2}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
    \caption{3}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3.png}
    \label{fig3}
  \end{subfigure}\\[-28pt]
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{4.png}
    \caption{4}
    \label{fig4}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{5.png}
    \caption{5}
    \label{fig5}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{6.png}
    \caption{6}
    \label{fig6}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \caption{images}\label{imagetable}
\end{centering}
\end{figure}
\end{centering}
```

Comment: The `centering` environment doesn't exist; use only `\centering` at the start and *definitely* not enclose `figure` in the inexistent environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your document, but since I don't have the `png` files, I re-created the figures using TikZ.

Doing so, I noticed that your problem is probably due to two factors:

1. The included graphics are exactly of the width of the allowable space (`\textwidth`)
2. The end-of-line character after your `\includegraphics` is equivalent to a white space, and since the graphic left no-room for that space, a new line is created inside the sub-figure.

It is that new (blank) line the one which causes the gap between rows. So I guess your problem will go away if you put a % after each of your `\includegraphics`. That % will "comment out" the carriage return and then the new blank line is not required.

The following MWE shows the solution, but using TikZ instead of `\includegraphics` for the figures, to improve the portability of the example.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Macro to create "sample" figures
\def\makefig#1#2{%  First the background color, second the number
\tikz{\fill[#1] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,\textwidth)%
  node[midway,black]{\textsf{\LARGE#2}};}%  <<--- This % is crucial
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering\lineskip=0pt
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
    \caption{1}%
    \makefig{red}{1}%
    \label{fig1}%
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
    \caption{2}
    \makefig{blue}{2}%
    \label{fig2}%
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
    \caption{3}
    \makefig{green}{3}%
    \label{fig3}%
  \end{subfigure}\\
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
    \makefig{cyan}{4}
    \caption{4}
    \label{fig4}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
    \makefig{yellow}{5}
    \caption{5}
    \label{fig5}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
    \makefig{magenta}{6}
    \caption{6}
    \label{fig6}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \caption{images}\label{imagetable}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And the result is:

[image: Output]

Comment: Rather than the `%` after `\includegraphics{...}` I suggest to put `\label{...}` just after `\caption{...}`. After the third subfigure, put `\\[-\lineskip]`.

Comment: Great answer!  One of the key take away points here is he added `\lineskip=0pt` just after beginning the `figure` (adding comments alone will still leave a small space if you don't 0 the lineskip)